# How to select a range in Excel VSTO

Tags: excel, vsto

I am creating an Excel VSTO Add-In in Visual Studio.

In a Dialog Box that opens when I click in the button triggering the Add-In, I would like to select a bunch of ranges.

How may I do it?

I have tried to use a Form, however I couldn't find this control (that is in a lot of Excel built-in dialog boxes) in the Toolbox... I have made also some research...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Application.InputBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.inputbox?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel__Application_InputBox_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_) method which does what you are looking for. If the 8th argument (`Type`) has a value of 8 - it will use the range selection. The return value will be the `Range` object. Also, you can put the default range into the box as the third argument.

```
Sub foo()   
        Dim r As Range
        Set r = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.InputBox("Sample", "sample", , , , , , 8)
        MsgBox r.Parent.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to select such input box in the form designer?

Comment: Eugene: you referred a Form, not a Control (within a form)...

Comment: Till now, I have implemented this in my form through the insertion of a button that when clicked opens the referred `InputBox` (which allows the range selection!). As I have read, Excel doesn't expose such control to VSTO. [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/21603c8f-6f7c-41ac-845e-a759c82daadb/excel-vsto-control-to-select-ranges?forum=csharpgeneral#21603c8f-6f7c-41ac-845e-a759c82daadb)